# How to validate zip code and city/state for weather app

Tags: android

So I am stuck right now on the topic of validating the zip code search for my weather app. I also want to validate the city and state search. For example, I only want 5 digits for the zip code when people search for a zip code. For the city, I don't want any numbers when they search for the city. 
Can someone help me?

```
public class WeatherRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ResponseDto> {
    private static final String WU_HOST = "http://api.wunderground.com";
    private static final String WU_API_KEY = "/api/36053e2befabcfe2";
    private static final String WU_DATA_FEATURE_CONDITION = "/conditions";
    private static final String WU_QUERY_TAG = "/q";
    private static final String WU_API_EXT = ".json";

    private String mZipCode;
    private String mCity;
    private String mState;

    public WeatherRequestTask(String zipCode) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(zipCode)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Zip Code is required");
        }
        mZipCode = zipCode;

    }

    public WeatherRequestTask(String city, String state) {
        mCity = city;
        mState = state;
        // TODO: validate city and state
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseDto doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ResponseDto myResponseDto = new ResponseDto();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {

            URL url;
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mZipCode)) {
                // use city and state query
                url = new URL(WU_HOST + WU_API_KEY + WU_DATA_FEATURE_CONDITION + WU_QUERY_TAG + "/" + mState + "/" +
                        mCity + WU_API_EXT);
            } else {
                // use zipCode query
                url = new URL(WU_HOST + WU_API_KEY + WU_DATA_FEATURE_CONDITION + WU_QUERY_TAG + "/" + mZipCode +
                        WU_API_EXT);
            }

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream())));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(temp);
            }

            JSONObject contentJson = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            Response response = Response.deserialize(contentJson.getJSONObject("response"));
            CurrentObservation currentObservation = CurrentObservation.deserialize(contentJson.getJSONObject
                    ("current_observation"));
            myResponseDto.setCurrentObservation(currentObservation);
            myResponseDto.setResponse(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return myResponseDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are they searching on, is it on an edittext or search widget?

Comment: It would be an edit text

Comment: Please post some of your code so it's easy to help you out

Comment: Well did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

For this part:

> For example, I only want 5 digits for the zip code when people search
>   for a zip code

You can try to check for the length of the zip code string:

```
if(zipCode.length==5){

  //zipcode is 5 characters
  //proceed with the search

}else{

  //zipcode is less or more than 5 
  //warn user or whatever
}
```

And for:

> For the city, I don't want any numbers when they search for the city.

```
if(mState.matches(".*\\d+.*"){

   //contains numbers
   //so don't carry forward or warn user

   }else{

   //Possibly what you want

   }
```

Comment: Just check matches `\\d` to find any number within the string

Answer (score 0):

This question has multiple tentacles.  What does "validate" mean?  There are databases that you can purchase that map ZIP codes into state/city pairs; the inverse problem is a bit more complicated.  The USPS publishes huge books that proffer THAT information.

As for cities without numbers, I've never heard of a city name that contains a number--other than Twentynine Palms, California, but that's a word.